# Debug QML in visual studio unable to connect to socket error

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-vs-addin

my environment, VS2017, QT 5.12.9 and QT VS Tool is 2.7.1 (rev20),
I enabled the QML debugging options in QT Project Settings, rebuilt it and ran the project, however it is stucked in this error

**QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QML Debugger: Connecting to socket {E363AFFB-190E-4564-9617-53A55B7594A6}...**

I read thru this article: https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/10/08/qml-debugging-visual-studio
and it says there should be two process running when i ran the application, but i only saw one.

Unfortunately there are no other articles or issues related to QML debugging in Visual studio.
What else I forgot to set or configured?

Comment: Are you working on a VS project (.vcxproj) or CMake project?

Comment: VS project (clicked from solution file).

Comment: As far as I can remember {E363AFFB-190E-4564-9617-53A55B7594A6} refers to the project itself. If you look it up in the project/solution files is that the one associated with the QML, which should be debugged? Has it got an executable output that can be run by the debugger as socket?  
Can you send a github link so I can look into this and help?

Comment: yes I opened the .vcxproj and it matched the <ProjectGuid> how do I check if executable output "can be run by debugger as a socket"?
unfortunately the repo is on a private repo and I cant put it public.

Comment: Too much work for me to try in your environment but you could try to apply this `#ifdef QT_DEBUG
static QQmlDebuggingEnabler qml_debug_enabler;
#endif
` to your main.cpp before the main() function and see. For me it did help while having somewhat similar issues there and there. Please let us know. It may need `#include <QtQmlDebug/QtQmlDebug>` or `#include <QQmlDebuggingEnabler>
`.